# ExtJS draggable panels with custom proxy?

Tags: extjs, draggable

I have read a few articles similar to this:

http://www.codeslower.com/2011/7/Using-the-draggable-property-in-ExtJS
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/drag_and_drop

I have a simple panel:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  draggable: true,

  title: 'Panel',
  html: 'Show work orders'
});
```

It allows me to drag around the container panel - even outside the container panel - but dropping constrains the element to the container.

I need a custom proxy to show the drop target location and size - not just a phantom image of the original panel. Can someone show me some simple code on how I might do this? I instantiate Ext.dd.DragSource and provide custom implementations. But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get started?

Sample code, articles, tutorials much appreciated :)

Alex